# Taking a queue of integers and making copies of that element

Tags: python, stack, queue

"Write a function named stutter that accepts a queue of integers as a parameter and replaces every element of the queue with two copies of that element in the original queue."

Example:

```
q1 = Queue()
queue.enqueue(1)
queue.enqueue(2)
queue.enqueue(3)
stutter(q1)
while not queue.isempty():
    print(queue.dequeue(), end=' ')
```

should give answer as "1 1 2 2 3 3"

```
class Queue:
        def __init__(self):
            self.items = []

        def is_empty(self):
            return self.items == []

        def enqueue(self, item):
            self.items.insert(0,item)

        def dequeue(self):
            return self.items.pop()

        def size(self):
            return len(self.items)

        def check_empty(self):
            if self.items == []:
                return True

def stutter(Q):
    queue=Queue()
    stack = Stack()
    while not queue.isempty():
        stack.push(queue.dequeue())

    while not stack.isempty():
        queue.enqueue(stack.pop())
```

That is the code that i have written, with that i can get it to print once and once only, i can't get it to duplicate and sort in order.

Comment: You are passing an argument to the stutter function (with 1 2 3 in it) but then not using it.  This argument is called q1 in the calling code and Q within the stutter function.   Because you don't do anything to Q in the stutter function (you create a new queue which will be empty), printing q1 after you return the function unsurprisingly returns the value of q1 before the function was called.  This is a very fundamental misunderstanding of how a function works, and you probably need to do some more research before asking your question (such as reading a textbook, if you have one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [17]:

def stutter(q):
    for i in range(q.size()):
        elm = q.dequeue()
        q.enqueue(elm)
        q.enqueue(elm)



In [18]:

q1 = Queue()
q1.enqueue(1)
q1.enqueue(2)
q1.enqueue(3)
stutter(q1)
print q1
[3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Note, I added a **str** method to the Queue class to see results.

```
class Queue:
        # SAME AS BEFORE
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.items)
```

You can also cheat because python does not have private instance variables.  I would not recommend it as an option.

```
def stutter(q):
    q.items = sorted([elm for elm in q.items] + [elm for elm in q.items])
```

If you want to return using the desired output:

```
q1 = Queue()
q1.enqueue(1)
q1.enqueue(2)
q1.enqueue(3)
stutter(q1)
print(' '.join([str(elm) for elm in q1.items]))
1 1 2 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this (can't test at the moment):

```
def stutter(queue):
    # iterate all items
    for _ in range(queue.size()):
        # store item in local context
        item = queue.dequeue()
        # push two *references* to item into the queue
        queue.enqueue(item)
        queue.enqueue(item)
```

This will iterate all items once, immediately pushing two copes to the back of the queue. The first pushed items should be the first once this iteration is over.

Notice that objects will be not be duplicated,and there will be two references to the same object in the queue.

**Tip:** there is already a queue implementation in Python. You can use it by importing `queue`

Comment: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".

Comment: @user3886897 sorry, forgot to replace `stack` with `queue` and use `range`. Try now.